# What is the difference in meaning between these four constructions?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverb-position

It is usual that some adverbs can be used in different positions in a sentence, which causes a change in meaning. And this can be difficult for a non-native speaker to understand. Here is an example which I really don't understand:

> 1. ***Really***, I can't sing.
> 2. I ***really*** can't sing.
> 3. I can't ***really*** sing.
> 4. I can't sing, ***really***.

Would you please show me  the difference in meaning between these constructions?

Answer (score 1):

Some translations:

```
Really, I can't sing.
```

I told you I can't sing, and I meant it.

```
I really can't sing.
```

Here, context and, in speech, emphasis, matter. "I *really* can't sing" means that I am a terrible singer. But "I really can't *sing*" means, for example, that I lip-sync pretty well, but I am not actually able to sing.

```
I can't really sing.
```

I can speak a song (like [Richard Burton in "Camelot,"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Vgs32MUDXY)),  but I don't believe that what I do can fairly be called "singing."

```
I can't sing, really.
```

This one could be used in place of any of the other three. Of the four, it relies most heavily in context. It does have an air of humility about it, though, As in "Yeah, some people call it singing, but [I have higher standards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W09ghiWskUk)."

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference in context in your examples. The position of the adverb in there is only to emphasise on a word or the rest of sentence;

1. Really, I can't sing. Here **Really** emphasises on the whole sentence after it.
2. I really can't sing. Here **really** emphasises on the modal-verb *can't*
3. I can't really sing. Here **really** emphasises on the action-verb *sing*
4. I can't sing, really. Here **really**, again, emphasises on the whole sentence before it.

Consider, however, the following with differences in context as well as meaning;

1. **Only** *I* watch anime in my free time. Ie, *only I* **watch anime in my free time**.
2. I **only** *watch* anime in my free time. Ie, what I do is *only watch*, which is **anime in my free time**
3. I watch **only** *anime* in my free time. Ie, I watch nothing but anime in my free time.
4. I watch anime **only** *in my free time*. Ie, I watch anime but only **in my free time**

Comment: This positioning of adverbs is slippery, though. If you consider "Basically, I don't agree."; "I basically don't agree"; "I don't, basically, agree" and "I don't agree, basically" you have the same form but the effects of the placing of the adverb is somewhat different from the "Really I can't sing" sentences. I think the differences depend on both the adverb and the verb. Basically, however, I _do_ agree with you.